# .Net 6 Blazor Server IIS Getting Current User returns apppool identity

Tags: .net, iis, blazor-server-side, windows-authentication

I have followed the documentation to get the Current Windows User using the AuthenticationStateProvider.  I've registered everything in program.cs (.Net 6 Blazor Server).

The App.razor page has the CascadingAuthenticationState code

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

If I run under Visual Studio using IIS Express my AD username is displayed in the Logon block correctly.

However if I deploy to IIS then I don't get the current logged in user.  I get the AppPool Identity that the appppool is set to run as.

[image]

I get the same results if I use the **AuthenticationStateProvider** or **IHttpContextAccessor**.  The username for both (when deployed on IIS ) just displays the IIS AppPool identity not the current username.

What am I missing?  Is it a setting in IIS or Blazor?

Comment: You have to reveal more (like code) about "I have followed the documentation to get the Current Windows User using the AuthenticationStateProvider", as it now gives you the application pool identity, not the actual logon user.

Comment: It looks like you are using windows authentication, in IIS you need to enable it in the corresponding site. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtSRQ.png).